# html css superimpose several images

Tags: html, css

How to superimpose several images in one line using css and html?
Ex: If my cursor is on image1, I want all images to the right be push to the right like that I can see image1

Here what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<body>
            <div class="deck">
                <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/kXlrGioGfFKOvibpsPzzGx16cP2.jpg" alt="testimage">
              <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/zzfwhweu5reCv2Loqzon7Q5WAd5.jpg" alt="testimage">
              <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/sGuZHYvu0mXeQCwvJ5yzk2Yoytq.jpg" alt="testimage">
              <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/4Ar01t6sW1ZZBcbz2R1wqjzIBdr.jpg" alt="testimage">

            </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.deck {overflow:hidden}
.deck img {position:relative; float:left;  width:185px; height:278px}
.deck img + img {margin-left: -160px;}
.deck img:hover {z-index:9999; border:1px solid red; background: pink}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/53ryuapx/

Comment: Are you open for a javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `~` selector to select all images following the one you hover. And as the images are positioned relatively, you can combine this with a `left` value:

```
.deck img:hover ~ img {
    left: 160px;
}
```

Might I even suggest you combine this with the relatively new `clip-path` property? Unfortunately [browser support is not great](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

```
.deck img:hover ~ img {
  left: 160px;
  clip-path: inset(0 160px 0 0)
}
```

**Edit:** There are several ways to animate this depending on the result you prefer. This might need some tewaking to get to the result you want, but this should get you started. What's happening here is we declare a keyframe animation called `slidein`. When an image is hovered, the images to the right are animated using `animation: slidein .2s`. See the effect in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53ryuapx/3/):

```
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  }
  100% {
    left: 160px;
    clip-path: inset(0 160px 0 0);
  }
}
.deck img:hover ~ img {
  left: 160px;
  clip-path: inset(0 160px 0 0);
  animation: slidein .2s;
}
```

Comment: But how add an animation when images are push to the right

Comment: @BenfMaappy I updated my answer with a CSS keyframe animation. I also played around with your fiddle and [did some small tweaks](https://jsfiddle.net/53ryuapx/4/). Hope this helps :o)

Comment: Thanks... I tried your exemple to add an animation to image push to the left but it didn't work. Really complicated